# Disabling reviews in django-oscar

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

Is it possible to completely disable functionality of 'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews' app in "django-oscar"?

As I see it's used in many places, so simple removal from `INSTALLED_APPS` doesn't work and perhaps simplest way is to just hide it in templates. Is there better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 0.5, there isn't a single setting that will turn reviews on and off: you'll need to perform a few steps.

1. Remove any references from the templates (as you mentioned).
2. Remove the reviews URLs.  This requires you to provide your own `app.py` for the catalogue app which doesn't link to the reviews `app.py`.  See http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-0.5/howto/how_to_disable_an_app.html

This is probably more difficult than it should be.  I'll look into providing a setting that disables reviews for 0.6.  Ticket here:
https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/issues/673

Comment: This is an update to the previous answer. As of version 0.6 (current master), add OSCAR_HIDDEN_FEATURES = ['reviews'] to the settings.py. Thanks David for implementing this.